# Help setting up Malware Analysis home lab

Tags: linux, virtualization

I am trying to set up a lab at home for basic malware analysis and I have come accross some issues. This is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

The problem I am having is that PFsense can't find the Kali machine (with ping), it does however find my Ubuntu server. Have I just completely messed up the Adapters or is something else wrong?

I have set up a PFsense box which has two network adapters:

Internet (Bridged with host wireless)

Virtual Network (**Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter**; IP 172.16.0.2 Netmask 255.255.255.0 Gateway 172.16.0.1).

I then have my ubuntu server (snort) which has two network adapters:

PFsense (**Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter**; IP 172.16.0.2 Netmask 255.255.255.0 Gateway 172.16.0.1)

Kali machine (**Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter2**; IP 172.16.0.3 Netmask 255.255.255.0 Gateway 172.16.0.1)

eth0: 172.16.0.2
netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 172.16.0.1

eth1: 172.16.0.3
netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 172.16.0.1

And finally I have the Kali machine (Analysis) which has one network adapter:

Snort (**Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter3**; IP 172.16.0.4 Netmask 255.255.255.0 Gateway 172.16.0.3)

eth0: 172.16.0.4
netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 172.16.0.3

Comment: Yes, you have completely messed up the configuration. IP networks have a purpose, you can't set the same network on separate adapters and hope it would work, not to mention the packets would be magically routed to the host you intend. However this is not a infosec question at all.

Comment: Well I can see what is your problem and I see that it will take a bit more work to do the changes, but just a bit so it wont take much. Anyway, try making drawing with all networking devices in place. Then for each routed subnet you need different LAN. Try to get  snort out and make sure all is working  without it and without issues. Then you can add snort.